# How to click a checkbox in an alert popup using Selenium C#. The checkbox does not have any xpath. Can't inspect as right click is disabled

Tags: c#, selenium

How to click a checkbox in an alert popup using Selenium C#. The checkbox does not have any xpath. Can't inspect as right click is disabled.

[image]

Comment: The screenshot appears to be the standard browser alert dialog, which is outside of the DOM. Can you provide some more details about how the alert is called?

Comment: The email has a confirmation link which when clicked opens up the browser with this alert.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not really possible using selenium since these alerts are browser or system level.
In java we've Sikuli or Robot class, you can try searching for the same or similar libraries in C# as well.